# find and replace a specific element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, while-loop

I am trying to locate "empty" in the array Bob, then after I find where empty is in the index i want to replace the word "empty" with "LEEROY JENKINS" Please forgive my lack of knowledge I am still very new to this and learning the best I can.

Problems:

1. int spindex() is not finding the correct index
2. empty is not being replaced

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int spindex(string x[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int tindex;

    while (x[i] != "empty" && i < n)
    {
        tindex = i;
        i++;
    }
    return tindex;
}

int main()
{
    string Bob[] = { "shaun", "empty", "tom", "empty", "chris", "sharon", "empty"};
    int pim = 7;
    int Q = spindex(Bob, pim);
    Bob[Q] = "LEEROY JENKINS";
    cout << Q << endl;
    cout << Bob[Q] << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        cout << Bob[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `pim` value is wrong. Why?

Comment: made it shorter forgot to change that, but doesnt change the result just a small miss type

Comment: It'll change the result dramatically if there's no "empty" in your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function

```
int spindex(string x[], int n)

{
    int i = 0;
    int tindex;

    while (x[i] != "empty" && i < n)
    {
        tindex = i;
        i++;
    }
    return tindex;
}
```

is wrong.  Except when the first element of the array has the value `"empty"` the function returns the index before the index of the element that contains the string.

Also the order of the sub-conditions in the condition of the while loop is also wrong.

Write it the following way

```
size_t spindex( const std::string a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n  && a[i] != "empty" ) i++;

    return i;
}
```

and call it like

```
size_t Q = spindex( Bob, sizeof( Bob ) / sizeof( *Bob ) );
```

A more general approach to write the function looks the following way

```
size_t spindex( const std::string a[], size_t n, const std::string &s )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n  && a[i] != s ) i++;

    return i;
}
```

And it can be called like

```
size_t Q = spindex( Bob, sizeof( Bob ) / sizeof( *Bob ), "empty" );
```

As an alternative you could use standard algorithm `std::find` declared in the header `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you constructed your loop:

```
while (x[i] != "empty" && i < n)
{
    tindex = i;
    i++;
}
```

First, `i` is 0. `tindex` gets set to 0, `i` gets set to 1.

Then the loop repeats, checking the condition. Oops! x[1] is "empty"! The loop ends and `tindex` is still 0.

That's why `Q` is 0 and why the wrong element is replaced.

Furthermore, you check `i < n` *after* trying to use `x[i]` (whoops).

You might as well just return `i`, since that is already the value you need:

```
int spindex(string x[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < n && x[i] != "empty") {
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2a55582affd519b))

---

In my opinion, the entire problem would be better constructed thus:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string Bob[] = { "shaun", "empty", "tom", "empty", "chris", "sharon", "empty"};

    auto it = std::find(std::begin(Bob), std::end(Bob), "empty");
    if (it == std::end(Bob)) {
        // No "empty" to replace!
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Replace first "empty" with "BOB"
    *it = "BOB";

    // Here is our array now
    std::cout << '[';
    for (const auto el : Bob)
        std::cout << el << ',';
    std::cout << ']' << '\n';
}

// Output: [shaun,BOB,tom,empty,chris,sharon,empty,]
```

#### [(live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d60c920fe1469e45))

Comment: could u suggest how I could fix this?

Comment: @ChronicArrow: I already did. I said it in words, and I provided a link to a live demonstration. I have now also provided a completely new solution, as a bonus.

Comment: thank you so much my rubbish internet had not caught me up to date with what you said! My apologies

Comment: @ChronicArrow: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and accept! :)